# Frustrated With Wpf DataGrid

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a tabcontrol and I place datagrid inside a tabcontrol... But I could not focus that Datagrid at the load event ... Focus means  I couldn't navigate through keyboard into it... I'm getting this problem only inside of the tab control otherwise it works fine...my sample project link as follows..

http://cid-0255f3152326d2b1.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/WPF%20Datagrid%20Problem?uc=1&nl=1

1. Please remember note that focus means I couldn't navigate a datagrid through keyboard
2. It should be in load event......Because it works fine in other events...
3. Datagrid should be placed inside a tab control... Because it works fine outside a tab control.....

I hope u wil help me... please help me out

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry dude,
   I had found an answer from
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1523d1c4-581d-44a9-86d8-61adb54ab2fb

Thanks,